# How Many DBContext's Should I have

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Using Entity I currently have dbcontext that has every table in it.

I'm wondering if that's what everyone does, or do you have a context per module for example. To me the dbcontext was a connection to map the models to a database, and since there is only one database, I only need one.

Before I get too far along I want to see if that's appropriate.

So 1 db context per database or many?

Comment: I've had the same thoughts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I went through this same process recently and found some great resources on the subject.  Here are a couple that were very helpful:

- [Shrink EF Models with DDD Bound Contexts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx).
- [How to decide on a lifetime for your ObjectContext](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/05/07/tip-18-how-to-decide-on-a-lifetime-for-your-objectcontext.aspx).

I was building a Desktop app, and I ended up using multiple contexts so that I could keep the lifetime tied to the module rather than the application.  This has worked out very well for me, and I like that my `DbContext` isn't swamped with `DbSets` and is limited to the ones that are relevant for the current module.

In an ASP.NET MVC app, it is different since the `DbContext` will only live as long as the request, and in those cases, I usually use a single `DbContext` to simplify things unless the database is very large.  With a large database, I would probably break it apart into multiple `DbContexts` just to limit the overhead and the clutter, and keep things compartmentalized.

Answer (score 0):

currently the EF hasnt been made to be broken down into diff dbContexts. [Here a great talk about it](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=efarchitecture&highlight=julie-lerman_efarchitecture-m1-overview%2a6,3!julie-lerman_efarchitecture-m3-archrepo%2a7,13!julie-lerman_efarchitecture-m2-boundedcontext%2a12!julie-lerman_efarchitecture-m4-testing%2a5#efarchitecture-m1-overview)

What we have done for this case that we have made a project diff from our MVC website just for the database generation and then have separate dbContexts for every requirement.

This way our dbContexts are never large and are easy to maintain